# How do I reload a UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, view, reloading

How do I reload a UIView after viewDidLoad + viewWillAppear have already been called (and the view displayed)?

If it helps - I'm loading it from a xib/nib file, and expect that calling the method should *only* trigger viewWillAppear on the controller, not to reload the *whole* nib file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about `[yourViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]`?